# Get data not in another table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT t.TBarcode,t.PlateNo 
from dbo.Transaction_tbl t
WHERE Status=0
```

Output:

```
TBarcode             PlateNo
-------------------- --------------------
6191112123456        123456
6191112123457        123458
6191112123459       123459
```

I have one more Table `EmailSendLog_tbl` Like This:

```
TBarcode             datetime
-------------------- --------------------
6191112123456        2013-07-19 11:12:25.000
6191112123464        2013-07-19 11:12:25.000
```

I want to get  all `TBarcode` and `PlateNo` that `TBarcode`  is not included in `EmailSendLog_tbl`, so I tried query something like this:

```
SELECT t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo 
from dbo.Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE Status = 0 and NOT in (SELECT TBarcode FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl)
```

But this is showing Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
WHERE Status=0 and t.TBarcode NOT IN(SELECT TBarcode FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl)
```

Comment: Thanks..Sir..This Is Worked Fine For me..Thanks for Your  Help

Answer (score 0):

You need put `t.TBarcode` before `not in`.

```
SELECT t.TBarcode,t.PlateNo 
from dbo.Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE Status=0 and t.TBarcode NOT in (SELECT TBarcode FROM dbo.EmailSendLog_tbl)
```

[IN syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)